# How to prove $(1+T)^\alpha (1+T)^\beta = (1+T)^{\alpha +\beta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am studying complex analysis using the textbook written by Serge Lange.  In it he defines as a formal power series and $\alpha $ any complex number:  $$(1+T)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{\alpha \choose n}T^n$$
In no other place does he formally define exponentiation so I am assuming that this is the only definition I can use.  Here, the binomial coefficient is defined in the usual way:  $${\alpha \choose n} = \frac{\alpha (\alpha - 1)(\alpha -2) \cdots (\alpha - n+1)}{n!}$$
I am trying to prove that $$(1+T)^\alpha (1+T)^\beta = (1+T)^{\alpha + \beta}$$
I realize you can use a counting argument if $\alpha $ was a natural number.  I can't use $\exp (z)^\alpha = \exp (\alpha z)$ because it is not proved in the text and I have tried in vain to prove it myself.  I have tried induction on $n$ as well.

Comment: The binomial coefficient as you've written it is not well-defined if $\alpha$ is non-integral.

Comment: @K.Jiang That's not true. $(1/2)(1/2-1)(1/2-2)/3!$ makes perfect sense, for $\binom{1/2}{3}$

Comment: Do you mean given $f_\alpha(T)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{\alpha \choose n}T^n$ how to prove that $f_{\alpha+\beta}(T)=f_{\alpha}(T)f_{\beta}(T)$, without knowing the link to exponentiation?

Comment: Be warned that there is no one way to define complex exponentiation

Comment: @FShrike That's true; I mistook $\alpha$ for $n$.

Comment: Matching the coefficients of each side of the identities (in powers of $T^n$) appears to yield $\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{\alpha}{m}\binom{\beta}{n-m}=\binom{\alpha+\beta}{n}$. But this isn’t exactly trivial either. (Perhaps induction on $n$ will be simplest.)

Comment: Identify the formal power series with the sequence of coefficients of $T^0,T^1,...$. Then show that the coefficient of $T^n$ is the same on both sides. Messy, but the usual reparameterisation of $(\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\})^2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical It is trivial for positive integers $\alpha,\beta$ and this implies the result as a polynomial in two variables vanishing at every pairs of positive integers is the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

I will use $a,b$ instead of $\alpha,\beta$. Then isolating the coefficient in $X^N$ on the sides, for $(1+X)^a(1+X)^b$, and for $(1+X)^{a+b}$, we have to show:
$$
\sum_{\substack{j,k\ge 0\\j+k=N}}\binom aj\binom bk = \binom{a+b}{N}\ .
\tag{$*$}
$$
This is a polynomial identity - that may be either true or false in the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[a,b]$ in the unknowns $a,b$. We know it is true for infinitely many values of $a$, and infinitely many values of $b$. So it is an identity for all $a,b$ in any field (of characteristic zero, we have denominators involved). The proof for $a,b$ natural numbers may work as follows. Consider $a$ red different toys, and $b$ blue different toys. Put them together in a bag and extract $N$ toys from the bag. This can be done in $\binom{a+b}N$ ways. Now split each extraction in its red and blue parts, and count correspondingly.

---

*Later EDIT:* Here is the standard argument for the fact that the difference polynomial of the sides in $(*)$ is identically zero. Denote it by $P=P(a,b)$, and write it as a polynomial in $b$ with coefficients polynomials in $a$:
$$
P(a,b)=P_N(a)b^N+\dots +P_1(a)b+P_0(a)\ .
$$
If all polynomial coefficients $P_j(a)$ are identically zero, everything is fine. Assume the contrary, and let $J$ be the maximal value of $j$ such that $P_j\not\equiv 0$.
Then there is a *natural* $a_0$ with $P_J(a_0)\ne 0$ since $P_J$ has only finitely many roots. Now consider the polynomial
$$
P(a_0,b)\ ,
$$ which is a non-zero polynomial in $b$, since its (main) coefficient in degree $J$ does not vanish. It has finitely many (at most $J$) roots, so there exists a natural $b_0$ which plugged in place of $b$ gives a non-zero value:
$$
P(a_0,b_0)\ne 0\ .
$$
This contradicts the identity we know for all naturals $a,b$. Our assumption is false. So $P\equiv 0$.

*Note:* The above argument is of algebraic nature, we use the fact that a polynomial of degree $N$ has at most $N$ roots (in a tacitly omitted field). A corollary to Bezout, if $x_0$ is a root of a polynomial $F$, then $f(X)$ is of the shape $F(X)=(X-x_0)G(X)$ with a polynomial $G$ - followed by induction with this step argument. Alternatively one can also use an argument based on analysis, the fact that a non-zero polynomial in one variable goes to $\pm\infty$ for its argument going to $\infty$.

Comment: Oh, i am definitively to slow in typing... this is the same as in the comment of @reuns...

Comment: Please explain "So it is an identity for all $a,b$ in any field.  Why?

Comment: @mjw the answer is edited now to give the (more or less) known (Hilbert/Zariski - type) argument.

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For real values of $\alpha $ and $\beta$  and $-1<T<1$ we have $$ (1+T)^\alpha(1+T)^\beta=(1+T)^{\alpha+\beta}\quad (*)$$ The identity $${\alpha+\beta \choose n}=\sum_{m=0}^n{\alpha \choose m}{\beta \choose n-m}\quad (**)$$ follows from the MacLaurin expansion of both sides of $(*).$ Fix a real value of $\alpha.$ Both sides of $(**)$ are polynomials of the complex variable $\beta.$ The equality $(**)$ holds for real values of $\beta,$ hence it holds for all complex values of $\beta$ and real values of $\alpha.$ Now fix a complex value of $\beta.$ Both sides of $(**)$ are polynomials of the complex variable $\alpha$ and the equality holds for real values of $\alpha.$ Hence $(**)$ holds for all complex values of $\alpha$ and $\beta.$

Comment: Please explain why "holds for all reals implies holds for all complex".  Are you using analytic continuation?

Comment: If two entire functions $f$ and $g$ (in our case polynomials) are equal one the real line then $f(z)=g(z)$ for any complex $z.$

Comment: Yes, Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your responses to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ a counting argument gives $$(1+t)^m(1+t)^n=(1+t)^{m+n} \, .$$
Then, for $x\in \mathbb{C}$ it follows
$$(1+t)(1+t)^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k} t^k + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k} t^{k+1} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left[ \binom{x}{k} + \binom{x}{k-1} \right] t^k \\
= 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{x+1}{k} t^k = (1+t)^{x+1} \, . \tag{1}$$
Now for $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ define
$$f(t)=(1+t)^x(1+t)^y \\
g(t)=(1+t)^{x+y} \, .$$

Clearly, $f(0)=g(0)=1$. Furthermore, by Equation (1)
$$(1+t)(1+t)^{-1}=1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (1+t)^{x-1}=(1+t)^{x-1}(1+t)(1+t)^{-1}=(1+t)^{-1}(1+t)^x$$
which gives
$$f'(t)=x(1+t)^{x-1}(1+t)^y+y(1+t)^x(1+t)^{y-1}=(x+y)(1+t)^{-1}f(t) \\
g'(t)=(x+y)(1+t)^{-1}g(t) \, .$$
Uniqueness of the first order ODE then implies $f=g$.